# How can I access the data of barchart in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I cannot find the data of any bar charts I have in the Dataset of Anylogic. Can anybody help me to find the data of the bar chart?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF. Please clarify this question. Currently , it is not clear what your problem really is ("cannot find the data of any bar charts I have in the Dataset" does not make sense). See some tips here: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow